# RPC error when reading excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, interop, rpc

Am getting this error when trying to read an excel sheet from a remote server using excel interop in my .net application.

"The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)"

When I run the app again, I dont get this error.May I know what could be the reason for this and how to avoid it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I was getting the same "weird" error, since I'm using excel interop (NS: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) on local machine having highest privilegies (event on target file/folder).

Did you by any chance reading multiple files using the same excel app instance?

If my guess is correct, try to create a new instance of excel for each file you need to parse, of course close the app when read completes.